# Serilog FilterExpression to check if all string Properties of a LogEvent meet a length constraint?

Tags: filtering, serilog

In my `appsettings.json`, I want to filter Serilog log events to include only log events where all scalar properties with string values meet a certain length constraint. In C# approach, the predicate would be

```cs
logEvent => logEvent.Properties.Values
          .OfType<ScalarValue>()
          .Select(x => x.Value)
          .OfType<string>()
          .All(x => x.Length <= 128);
```

In a json approach, based on the docs,
I sort of think that there may be a hack with regular expressions like

```
Contains(@Properties[*], /^.{0,128}$/)
```

or maybe

```
Length(@Properties[*]) <= 128
```

but apparently none of these works

Any ideas how to check if any string properties is below length limit?

Answer (score 0):

The above filter expressions do not work because Serilog filter expression compiler has a special treatment for `Properties`: at some point in the internal filter expression compilation pipeline, `Properties['somekey']` gets replaced with `somekey`.
This is logical, because in effect `Properties['somekey']` is in fact an access to a property named `somekey`. The wildcards `?` and `*` are not exempt from this rule.
This explains why the examples in the question do compile to some kind of `Func<FilterExpression, object>` internally, but fail to produce the results I expected.

Comment: Hi! I'm currently working on improving expression support in Serilog, so I'm interested in your example :-) ... Since the `*` wildcard means _all_ properties, this problem might also stem from the existence of `null` or non-string (e.g. numeric) properties - these would fail the condition. HTH!

Comment: Hi @NicholasBlumhardt I was just exploring how to express an "any" condition on `Properties` in a json config FE. We actually ended up with an enricher adding a "technical" `maxStringProperty` prop to events and a sublogger with a filter that filtered log events based on that prop. My hypothesis that `@Properties` may be a special case is based on https://github.com/serilog/serilog-filters-expressions/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Filters.Expressions/Filters/Expressions/Compilation/Properties/PropertiesObjectAccessorTransformer.cs L13-25 which transforms access by key into a `FilterPropertyExpression`